# What is the least-dirty way to expose private javascript vars for testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, scope, private

I've got a state machine in JS which (to simplify) has an initial state that is only set before anything happens.

```
define(function() {
  var state = 'initial',
      exports = {};

  exports.getState = function() {
    return state;
  };

  exports.doSomething = function() {
    state = 'newState';
  };

  return exports;
});
```

Because the state is permanent until the app is reloaded, after the first test the state will never be 'initial' again, and so I need a way to reset it.

Which is the least dirty way of doing this? Should I...

a) simply make state public but mark it as private with _?

```
define(function() {
  var exports = {};

  exports._state = 'initial'

  exports.getState = function() {
    return this.state;
  };

  exports.doSomething = function() {
    this.state = 'newState';
  };

  return exports;
});
```

b) make the state writable via a function?

```
define(function() {
  var state = 'initial',
      exports = {};

  exports.getState = function() {
    return state;
  };

  exports.doSomething = function() {
    state = 'newState';
  };

  if(window.xxTests) {
    window.xxTests.Module = {
      setState: function(newState) {
        state = newState;
      }
    };
  }

  return exports;
});
```

(where xx is the app prefix and xxTests is defined only as part of the test runner)

or

c) do something else entirely I didn't think of?

Your thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why not adding  `exports.reset = function() { state = 'initial'; };`?

Comment: It's an option but like the other options it enables write access to a private var when it should be read-only in production environments.

Answer (score 0):

**General answer:** The better way of testing a component without exposing private data is putting test code inside that component. Of course this becomes quite dirty if your language doesn't support this in a clean way (like D does).

**In your case** I suggest the second way (I mean your option b), because it doesn't expose private data unless explicitly needed (only during tests):

```
if(youAreDoingATest)
{
    exports.reset=function() { state='initial'; };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of context on how you're running your tests.

Most test runners have `beforeEach()`, `beforeAll()`, `afterEach()`, and `afterAll()` methods that can be used for setup and tear-down that run as their names suggest.

To solve your specific problem I would not change your "state machine" code at but instead I would create a new state machine in the `beforeEach()` function so that each test gets the new function object with the state set to 'initial'.